# deleting line in linux text file with C++

Tags: c++

i need help in how i should write a code for doing a delete line using c++ in linux. what i have in the text file is listed below

> description:amount:date
>   electricity bill:100:25jan2015
>   telephone bill:100:25jan2015
>   telephone bill:50:25jan2015

i want to do it so that when the user selects option b to remove the expense that the user input and to prevent the program from deleting duplicate data the user will have to input the amount and date. thank you.

and the temp.txt is used to store what was not deleted before being renamed to Expense.txt so if telephone bill value 100 was removed it would become

> electricity bill:100:25jan2015
>   telephonebill:50:25jan2015

```
void deleteexpensesdata(string& expense, string& texpense, double& amount,  string& date){
int check, x=0;
ifstream Expenses("Expense.txt");
ofstream temp("temp.txt");
cout << "\n";
cout << "Enter Type of Expense you wish to remove" << endl;
cin >> texpense;

while(Expenses >> expense >> amount >> date){
    if(texpense!=expense){//if there are expenses with different name, input their data into temp file
        temp << expense << ":" << amount << ":" << date <<endl;
    }
    if(texpense==expense){// if user entered correct name, x=1 for later output message that the user data has been deleted
       x=1; 
    }
}

Expenses.clear();
Expenses.seekg(0, ios::beg);
Expenses.close();
temp.close();
remove("Expense.txt");
rename("temp.txt","Expense.txt");
if(x==0){//x was set to 0 at start, so if it didn't change, it means there is error
    cout << "Remove of Expense failed" << endl;
}
else{//if x is not = 0 then remove is successful
    cout << "Expenses has been removed" << endl;
}
 }
```

the code that calls the function is below

```
        cout << "Remove Expense.\n";
        deleteexpensesdata(expense, texpense, amount, date);
        cout << "Expense Date has been delete. \n" << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
```

Comment: You forgot to say what your current code's doing - i.e. what output you get in `temp.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below gets the user input and converts the double to string and turns all 3 variable into line with the delimiter ":" as seen in your example input and after u open the file u get the line that does not match into a temp file and rename the file essentially removing it.

```
double expamt;
    string line, expdesc, exptrans;
    cout << "Please Enter Expense: \n";
    cin >> expdesc;
    cout << "Please Enter Amount: \n";
    cin >> expamt;
    string newamt = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << expamt) )->str();
    cout << "Date of Transaction: (e.g 20jan2015)\n";
    cin >> exptrans;

    string input = expdesc + ":" + newamt + ":" + exptrans;

    ifstream myfile;
    ofstream tempfile;
    myfile.open("Expense.txt");
    tempfile.open("temp.txt");
while (getline(myfile, line))
{
    if (line != input)
        tempfile << line;
}
    cout << "\nExpense " << expdesc << " has been removed \n" <<endl;
    myfile.close();
    tempfile.close();
    remove("Expense.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "Expense.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

First an advice: You should learn to use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Your code has several logic errors, for instance the line:

```
Expenses >> expense >> amount >> date
```

might not be doing what you're expecting to do, since the operator `>>` don't deal (by default) with character ':' as a separtor or delimiter.

Also, don't use a variable (`x`) for checking input errors, **ifstream** and **ofstream** objects has functions like: [ifstream::good](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good), [ifstream::fail](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) and [ifstream::bad](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/bad).

However you could user a `x` for check if any change was made, if not you don't need the file operations:

```
remove("Expense.txt");
rename("temp.txt","Expense.txt");
```

Said that, your comment con be readed:

> x was set to 0 at start, so if it didn't change, it means there is error

Actually that's wrong, `x == 0` also means the condition `texpense==expense` never got true.

**Recomendations**

1. You could use [std::iftream::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) and change the delimiter to `:`.
2. You could use [std::iftream::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) combined with regex and [std::regex::search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

I think the first is easier (if `:` aren't sorrounded by spaces), the second is more elegant as less error prone. Is up to you.