# update and delete data from file in c++

Tags: c++

How can I update data from file in c++ without display the old data? I want to delete specific data and update. For example I want to update the name only and another time update gpa only with delete the old gpa?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k=0;
    string line;
    string find;
    char name[25];
    int id=0; 
    float gpa=0;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("data.txt");

    while(k!=3){

        cout<<"press 1 for adding data"<<endl;
        cout<<"press 2 for update "<<endl;

        cin>>k;

        if(k==1)
        { 
            cout<<"enter ID "<<endl;
            cin>>id;

            cout<<"enter Name"<<endl;
            cin>>name;

            cout<<"enter GPA "<<endl;
            cin>>gpa;

            myfile<<name<<endl;
            myfile<<id<<endl;
            myfile<<gpa<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        }

        if(k==2)
        {

            cout<<"name u want to update "<<endl;
            cin>>find; 
            ifstream file;

            file.open("data.txt");
            while (!file.eof() && line!=find)
            {

                getline(file,line);
            }

            cout<<"enter ID "<<endl;
            cin>>id;

            cout<<"enter Name"<<endl;
            cin>>name;

            cout<<"enter GPA "<<endl;
            cin>>gpa;
            myfile<<name<<endl;
            myfile<<id<<endl;
            myfile<<gpa<<endl<<endl<<endl;
        }
        if(k==3){
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to copy all the others record to temporary file and then write the new record and delete the old one and rename the temporary to file name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [deleting line in linux text file with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062055/deleting-line-in-linux-text-file-with-c)

Answer (score 2):

First you have to copy all the other records to a temporary file eg. `temp.txt` and then delete the old file `data.txt` and rename `temp.txt` to `data.txt`. Now write the new record to file `data.txt`.

### **code:**

```
if(k==2)
 {
    cout<<"name u want to update "<<endl;
    cin>>find;

    ifstream myfile2; //for reading records
   myfile2.open("data.txt");

    ofstream temp;
    temp.open("temp.txt");
    while (getline(myfile2, line))
    {
      if (line != find)
        temp << line << endl;
    }
    myfile2.close();
    temp.close();
    remove("data.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "data.txt");

    //Now add new Record to file
    cout<<"enter ID "<<endl;
    cin>>id;

    cout<<"enter Name"<<endl;
    cin>>name;

    cout<<"enter GPA "<<endl;
    cin>>gpa;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("data.txt", ios::app | ios::out);
    myfile<<name<<endl;
    myfile<<id<<endl;
    myfile<<gpa<<endl<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Comment: On any platform but Windows, you don't need to call `remove()`, since `rename()` will atomically overwrite the destination file.

Answer (score 1):

Line by line read old file and copy lines to a new file. When you find the line which you want to update, change it with your line and copy it to the new file. When you reach EOF, delete old file and rename new file with the name of old file.

It will be something like that:

```
int replace_line(const char *fname, const char *oldline, const char* newline)
{
    int done = 0;

    /* Open templorary file */
    FILE *newfp = fopen("file.tmp", "a");
    if (newfp != NULL) 
    {
        /* Open exiting file */
        FILE *oldfp = fopen(fname, "r");
        if(oldfp != NULL)
        {
            ssize_t read;
            size_t len = 0;
            char * line = NULL;

            /* Line-by-line read from exiting file */            
            while ((read = getline(&line, &len, oldfp)) != -1) 
            {
                if(strstr(line, oldline) == NULL) fprintf(newfp, "%s", line);
                else fprintf(newfp, "%s", newline);
            }

            /* Clean up memory */
            fclose(oldfp);
            if (line) free(line);

            done = 1;
        }

        fclose(newfp);
        remove(fname);
        rename("file.tmp", fname);

        return done;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are giving a C example to a C++ question, it would be more helpful to show an example using iostream functions. Also, on any platform but Windows, you don't need to call `remove()` before the `rename()`; the latter is an atomic operation that will cause the old file to be deleted automatically.